# Passing Argument from JPanel into JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I had a problem which I didn't figure out how to solve it. I'm reading now (JAVA how to program 9th edition). My application (Chapter 9, page 390) needs to create a random number of different shapes with different colors, then layout (JFrame) contains a JPanel  - which has shapes - and a JLabel - which has numbers of these different shapes.
I created the random shapes with random colors, but the number of shapes cannot be passed correctly to main method. It always show me 0.

> RandomShapes.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class RandomShapes extends JPanel{

public int counter;
private Random random = new Random();

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    drawLines(g);
}

public void drawLines(Graphics g){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < random.nextInt(20) ; i++){
        g.setColor(generateColor());
        g.drawLine(random.nextInt(getWidth()), random.nextInt(getHeight()), random.nextInt(getWidth()), random.nextInt(getHeight()));
        counter++;
    }

}

private Color generateColor(){
    Color color = new Color(random.nextInt(255), random.nextInt(255), random.nextInt(255));

    return color;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return String.format("%d",counter);
}
}
```

> RandomShapesTest.java

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class RandomShapesTest{
public static void main(String[] args){
    RandomShapes shapes = new RandomShapes();
    JFrame application = new JFrame();

    JLabel status = new JLabel(shapes.toString());


    application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    application.add(shapes);
    application.setSize(600,600);
    application.add(status, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    application.setVisible(true);
}   
}
```

By the way, a little trick may be more helpful than full answer :)

Regards,,,

Comment: Do you mean "counter" is always 0 ? I am sorry I don't understand your question. What do you mean by "cannot be passed correctly to main method". But counter seems not to be created at the right place.

Comment: ,Consider creating your count in the  class constructor and not in its paint components method.

Comment: counter variable counts the number of random shapes (lines in my example) has been created, then I want to view this number in JLabel.

Comment: :Your problem is that paint component is only called when the component is painted not when it is constructed. Your  count variable is 0 at the time  of class construction.

Comment: Counter is local to your paint, you should create it in your class constructor as Hovercraft (+1) says. By the way accessing local variables must NEVER be made as "public" reference but by using getters and setters. That said, for the problem, Hovercraft gave the answer.

Comment: First of all you should consider using correct design pattern (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-142890.html).  After that your data flow would be more predictable, now it's a mess.

Answer (score 1):

The `counter` value is incremented on every repaint. This means that whenever you resize the window or do something else that triggers a repaint, your counter will increase and display wrong values.

However, the `JLabel` currently displays 0 because the first repaint happens after you read the count value in the `toString()` method.

I suggest you build your objects to be drawn in a method that is called by the `RandomShapes` constructor. You build a list of `Line2D.Float` objects and you would paint the lines in your paint method.

Comment: Just to be clear: even if the `counter` value increases, the label will not update itself auto-magically. There is a mechanism needed to update the text in the label when the `counter` changes

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all you useful answers guys, I solved this problem as following :

> CreateShapes.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class CreateShapes {

    private Graphics g;
    private Color myColor;
    private int x1, x2, x3, x4;

    public CreateShapes(int x1, int x2, int x3, int x4, Color myColor){
        this.x1 = x1;
        this.x2 = x2;
        this.x3 = x3;
        this.x4 = x4;
        this.myColor = myColor;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(myColor);
        g.drawLine(x1, x2, x3, x4);
    }
}
```

> DrawShapes.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DrawShapes extends JPanel{

    private Random randomNumber = new Random();
    private CreateShapes[] shapes;
    private int shapeCounter;

    public DrawShapes(){

        setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        shapes = new CreateShapes[1+randomNumber.nextInt(15)];

        for(int i = 0 ; i < shapes.length ; i++){
            int x1 = randomNumber.nextInt(600);
            int x2 = randomNumber.nextInt(600);
            int x3 = randomNumber.nextInt(600);
            int x4 = randomNumber.nextInt(600);

            Color color = new Color(randomNumber.nextInt(255), randomNumber.nextInt(255), randomNumber.nextInt(255), randomNumber.nextInt(255));

            shapes[i] = new CreateShapes(x1, x2, x3, x4, color);
        }

        shapeCounter = shapes.length;
    }

    public int getShapesNumber(){
        return shapeCounter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);

        for(CreateShapes shape : shapes){
            shape.draw(g);
        }
    }
}
```

> RandomShapesTest.java

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class RandomShapesTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        DrawShapes drawShapes = new DrawShapes();
        JFrame application = new JFrame();

        String status = String.format("Lines : %d", drawShapes.getShapesNumber());

        JLabel statusBar = new JLabel(status);

        application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        application.add(drawShapes);
        application.add(statusBar,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        application.setSize(600,600);
        application.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Regards,,,